# Port number is not correct while connecting to sql server

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, driver

I am trying to connect to SQL Server as follows from Netbeans. I have sqljdbc4.jar in my Libraries forlder of the project.

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    connRemoteforGlobal = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.x.xxx:1433/test",RemoteSQLServerUser,RemoteSQLServerPass);

    if(connRemoteforGlobal != null)
    {
        System.out.println("Connection Successful !");
    }
}
catch(SQLException ex2){
    ex2.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Error Trace in Connection : " + ex2.getMessage());
}
```

And getting the following error:

Is there any additional settings required in netbeans or in my connection? Port number?

```
Error Trace in Connection : The port number 1433/test is not valid.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The port number 1433/test is not valid.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:691)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at mypackage.myclass.call(myclass.java:408)
    at mypackage.myclass.call(myclass.java:25)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1259)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: No setting is required in netbean,are you sure that port is correct ?

Comment: That's a default port suggested to use everywhere . For example here, http://ruby.fgcu.edu/courses/mpenderg/GettingStartedWithNetbeans/SQLSERVERandNetbeans.html

Answer (score 16):

It should be:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.x.xxx:1433;databaseName=Test
```

This is the format:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx

Look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988.aspx for properties. Anyway, 1433 seems to be the default port number so it is not necessary to specify it.

Comment: BTW I am connecting to SQL Server 2008 and the link has setting for SQL Server 2012. ?

Comment: I would guess that it has not changed. Give it a try.

Comment: I changed it like this: `connRemoteforGlobal = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.x.xxx\test;databaseName=mydatabasename",RemoteSQLServerUser,RemoteSQLServerPass);` but nothing seems to be printing now. Not even, connection successful message

Comment: Why do you keep adding test after xx.xx.x.xxx. The documenation clearly states that it is not the correct format? I even gave you a connection string.

Comment: Because the documentation says` instanceName (Optional) is the instance to connect to on serverName. If not specified, a connection to the default instance is made`. anyways, even after removing it, I don't see any changes : I did the following this time :`jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.x.xxx;databaseName=mydatabasename",RemoteSQLServerUser,RemoteSQLServerPass`